# How do I retrieve a missing number?Cash register- determine the appropriate change

Tags: python

I have already written the program but when I run it  I am getting shorted by one penny. (The problem is at the very bottom)

My instructor said it was fine because we haven't learned  what to add to the string (?) to prevent that from happening, but said we could try and find out what to add if we wanted to.

Here's the the problem:

```
price=float(input("What is the price of the item?"))
tax=round(price*0.0725,2)
grandTotal=price+tax
tendered=float(input("How much money did customer give you?"))

print(format("The price of the item is $","26"), format(price,"6.2f"))
print(format("The tax on the item is","26"), format(tax, "6.2f"))
print(format("The total cost is","26"), format(grandTotal, "6.2f"))
print(format("You tendered","26"), format(tendered, "6.2f"))
change=tendered-grandTotal
print(format("Your change is","26"), format(change, "6.2f"))
```

#### Calculating the breakdown of change

```
penny=int(change*100)    #transform change into pennies

dollars=penny//100       #how many dollars are there
pennyleft= penny%100     #remainder operator to find how many pennies are left

quarters= pennyleft//25 #number of quarters
pennyleft=pennyleft%25  #remainder operator to find how many pennies are left

dimes=pennyleft//10     #number of dimes
pennyleft=pennyleft%10

nickels=pennyleft//5    #number of nickels
pennyleft=pennyleft%5

pennies=pennyleft//1    #number of pennies
pennyleft=pennyleft%1
print("Your change is:")
print( format(dollars, "5"), "dollar bills,") 
print( format(quarters, "5"), "quarters,")
print( format(dimes, "5"), "dimes,")
print( format(nickels, "5"), "nickels, and")
print( format(pennies, "5"), "pennies.")
```

And this is the output;
    What is the price of the item?5.00
    You owe a total of $ 5.36
    How much money did customer give you?10.00
    The price of the item is $  5.00
    The tax on the item is    0.36
    The total cost is         5.36
    You tendered             10.00
    Your change is            4.64
    Your change is:
      4 dollar bills,
      2 quarters,
      1 dimes,
      0 nickels, and
      3 pennies.

So my issue is that the 3 pennies should actually be 4. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with floating point numbers, and as such the result may be just a bit more or less than you'd expect. Not all floating point numbers can be stored *exactly* in a computer. It may sound suprising but it's really not that different from the usual decimal system. After all, you cannot "store" `1/3` in a decimal number either! It will be `0.3333333...` (an infinite amount of `3`s omitted for clarity and lack of storage space).

If you test the values you get by printing out more decimals, you will find that this line

```
print(format("Your change is","26"), format(change, "6.20f"))
```

shows

```
Your change is             4.63999999999999968026
```

and, since `int(x)` always rounds down (more specifically, it "truncates towards zero" ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int))), the next line

```
penny=int(change*100)
```

only cuts off the excess decimals so you end up with `463`. After this, the number is converted to an integer and so no further floating point mishaps occur – but it's too late.

To get the proper calculation, all you have to do is add another `round`:

```
penny=int(round(change*100))    #transform change into pennies
```

and this will reimburse that lost penny.